# Glslang VS Project Setup

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, vulkan

I am following this [quick tutorial](http://forestsharp.com/glslang-cpp/) and I am not sure how to do the project setup part for my pre-existing VS 2017 project that uses the [LunarG Vulkan SDK](https://www.lunarg.com/vulkan-sdk/) which includes the glslang and SPIRV folders. I tried using the table found [here](https://cognitivewaves.wordpress.com/cmake-and-visual-studio/) to convert the cmake commands in the tutorial; I was able to include the glslang directory but I cannot figure out what I should be adding to properties->linker->input->additional dependencies for linking with glslang and SPIRV. Do I have to somehow compile these first then link to them? In which case how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I have to somehow compile these first then link to them? In which case how do I do that?

Yes.  If you want to use the glslang tools at runtime instead of at build time, you need to first build them.  The VulkanSDK contains the glslang source code, but not binaries.  Since the interface to glslang is C++, not C like Vulkan, producing a binary that would work for everyone is basically a non-starter.

The tutorial you link to includes this:

> ```
> add_subdirectory(${LIB_DIRECTORY}/glslang)
> ```

Which basically means "include this other CMake based project in my own", which would in turn mean that it would have the same build settings as your own CMake based project.  In order to bypass CMake you would need to construct a Visual Studio project for glslang from scratch.

My advice to you is to stop trying to fit the tutorial into your pre-existing Visual Studio project and just use CMake to generate your VS project so that you can follow the tutorial directly.  It's extremely unlikely that whatever settings you have in your pre-existing VS project can't be replicated in a CMake based VS project *very quickly*.

Alternatively, you can learn just enough CMake to create a project for glslang and build it, at which point you'll be able to use the binaries it creates as your linker inputs, *BUT* you'll need to make sure that the project settings in glslang generated project are sufficiently close to your own, in particular the Runtime Library and the 32/64 bit-edness and make sure that you don't mix and match release and debug builds across the dependency.

Here is a simple recipe for building glslang, assuming you have CMake installed and the VulkanSDK correctly installed:

```
mkdir %VULKAN_SDK%\..\glslang
cd %VULKAN_SDK%\glslang
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 15 Win64" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=%VULKAN_SDK%\..\glslang
cmake --build . --config Release 
cmake --build . --config Debug
cmake --build . --config Release --target INSTALL 
cmake --build . --config Debug --target INSTALL
```

Comment: There seems to be a `shaderc` static library. Isn't that the thing that is supposed to be used by the users?

Comment: I've honestly never noticed that library, and I don't see where it's use is documented.  So if it does what this guy needs, great, but without understanding it's nature, I'm not going to recommend it.  Additionally, the name suggests it's based on the Google shader compiler, not the glslang reference compiler, and so again, if this guy is following a tutorial that may depend on glslang, using shaderc isn't a good idea.

Comment: From the README: "Shaderc wraps around core functionality in glslang and SPIRV-Tools".